# How to commit changes made after git rm --cached

Tags: git

I wanted to remove some of the files from my local repository and so I removed them by means of the `git rm --cached` command. Now I would like to push the repository (without the unwanted files). Should I first `commit` the changes? Should I `git add .` before the commit?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of practice, you should always do `git status` if you be unsure as to the state of your local repo.  I believe that if you run `git status`, you will already see the `git rm --cached` changes staged.  If not, then you may have to `git add` these changes.  Then, make a commit and push to your remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `git add`: the `git rm --cached` has already modified your index and removed those files.

A simple commit+push will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to push some files in your project, you may need to add the **.gitignore** file and ignore the files that you don't want to push.

The **.gitignore** file like this:

```
*.apk
*.ap_
*.dex
*.class
bin/
gen/
out/
.gradle/
build/
local.properties
proguard/
*.log
.navigation/
captures/
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
*.jks
.externalNativeBuild
google-services.json
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json
```